# Simple algorithm/method to generate the sequence

Tags: algorithm, math

http://oeis.org/A005773

I looked into that page but most of the abbreviations didn't make any sense.

> G.f.: 2x/(3x-1+sqrt(1-2x-3x^2)) - Len Smiley
>   (smiley(AT)math.uaa.alaska.edu).

Does G.f implies generating function?. Substituting any values for x almost yields a square root of a negative number(imaginary). How does it generate the sequence?
Any help would be welcome.

Edit:
The bottom of the page has some examples using specialized languages like Mathematica,Maple,etc., which I am not familiar with. Any explanation with languages like C,Java or Python would be really helpful.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  But yes, g.f. stands for generating function; the coefficients of the Taylor series of that expression generate the terms of the sequence.  You can use one of the other formulae (say one of the recurrences) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,DSM. I do agree this falls somewhere between math and programming.

Comment: off topic -- belongs on math.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a sequence `{a0, a1, a2, a3, ... }` then its generating function is

```
f(x) = sum aj x^j
```

For example, the sequence `{1, 1, 1, 1, ... }` has

```
f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...
```

Conveniently, this function has a closed expression

```
f(x) = 1 / (1 - x)
```

and so we say that `1 / (1 - x)` is the generating function for `{1, 1, 1, 1, ... }`.

For your function `2x / (3x - 1 + sqrt(1 - 2x - 3x^2))` you need to expand this function in its Taylor sequence about `x0 = 0` and then you will have the terms of the sequence.

If you use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B2x%2F%283x-1%2BSqrt%5B1-2x-3x%5E2%5D%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+7%7D%5D), you'll see the first few terms are

```
1, 1, 2, 5, 13, 35, 96, 267, ...
```

and then if you use [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C13%2C35%2C96%2C267&sort=&language=english&go=Search) you'll get

> A005773         Number of directed animals of size n (or directed n-ominoes in standard position).

which is right back to where you started showing that this generating function really does generate this sequence.

There's a really fun book called [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) dedicated to this subject that you can download for free. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, G.f. means generating function. The series expansion of this expression at x = 0 gives a power series in x whose coefficients are the sequence.

[Wolfram Alpha's expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B2x/%283x-1%2bSqrt%5B1-2x-3x%5E2%5D%29,%20%7Bx,%200,%2010%7D%5D)

My input was

```
Series[2x/(3x-1+Sqrt[1-2x-3x^2]), {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Wolfram Alpha is very handy!